# How does Environments > Raster analysis > Cell size works in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, resolution

How does Environments > Raster analysis > Cell size works, when creating a raster from a polygon using ArcGIS?

I have tried to handle both "Maximum of Inputs" and "Minimum of Inputs" and nothing seems to change: the tool creates the same raster.

Answer (score 4):

Max and Min assume your inputs are existing rasters. If you combine 2 rasters together of different cell sizes and use the 'minimum' option, the cell size of the output raster will be the lowest cell size between the inputs.

A cell size parameter value of '20' would use the units of your data, ie. if your data is in UTM - which is metres - your output raster would have a 20m cell size.

Answer (score 0):

How does Environments > Raster analysis > Cell size works, when creating a raster from a polygon?

It may not work unless one of your inputs is a raster. When creating a raster from a polygon, your only input is a vector polygon layer. I would set my cell size environment variable to an existing raster that you would hope for your output data to match (and also set the Snap Raster to the same layer). If you don't need to work with other rasters, then I would just specify a number.